# Hiding parameters in createURL - YII Framework

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager

I am trying to pass array of values as parameter to controller action in YII Framework,
My URL is like very hard to see with array values.

Calling Controller Action:

```
var jString = JSON.stringify(val);  
window.open ('".$this->createUrl('campaign/reportdrill')."/id/'+jString,'_blank');
```

URL Formed :

```
http://sks14/viacrm/campaign/reportdrill/id/%5B%7B%22Campaign%22:193,%22Filter%22:651,%22crm_post_code_categ_id%22:%221%22,%22crm_campaign_post_code_id%22:%22296%22,%22todate%22:%2214-05-2014%22,%22fromdate%22:%2201-05-2014%22,%22agent%22:%22%22%7D%5D
```

How to hide this parameter from user or is anyother way to pass array of values to controller action ?

Comment: try passing in `$_POST` parameter, **POST method**

Comment: Can you give any example ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way to pass parameters via the GET method of URLs. If you want to 'hide' the URL, use an AJAX load instead.

```
var jString = JSON.stringify(val);
$('body').load('".$this->createUrl('campaign/reportdrill')."/id/'+jString);
```

However, AJAX load cannot apply to opening a new window. You will still need to use your URL for that purpose.

Comment: but i need it in  separate browser

Comment: getting render design in ajax onsuccess() how to open this in new browser tab